# How to Display Array Value to through Index in DUSTJS

Tags: json, templates, dust.js

My Question is simple: Is there anyway to display array value through its index in DUSTjs syntax.

Sample JSON :

```
{ names: 
    [
        "Jhon", 
        "Peter", 
        "Curly"
    ] 
}
```

with the above json sample, I just want to display any of the names through its index in *DUST* syntax.

Note: We are able to display all names, but i need any of the names to be displayed as output through its index (Eg : `names[0]` something like this or by any other way).

Answer (score 1):

when iterating `$idx` will give you the index so for example showing them as `<li>` elements:

```
{#names}
<li>
    {names[$idx]}
<li>{~n}
{/names}
```

otherwise just plain

```
{names[1]}
```

will give you first element

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to achieve:

`{names[0]}` gives you `Jhon`

`{names[2]}` gives you `Curly`

and so on.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you use the  linkedin dustjs fork, you can do that:

take a look here: http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/test/test.html. There are a lot of examples.

This is the wikki: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki

and this is the code repo:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the solution by using                    {#names}{@eq key="{$idx}" value="0" }
   {.}
{/eq}{/names}                                                                             With Syntax i can able to display the 0th index value - "Jhon" as output.